# Can RDF/SPARQL be used for sub-graph matching?

Tags: sparql, sequence, rdf, knowledge-graph

I would like to build a knowledge graph of a set of instances, where each instance is itself a collection of **ordered** sub-instances. As a simple example, let's assume my instances are chains of marbles `{CHAIN1, CHAIN2, CHAIN3, ...}` and the sub-instances are colored marbles `{CHAIN1: YELLOW-RED-BLUE-RED; CHAIN2: BLUE-YELLOW-GREEN; CHAIN3: GREEN-RED-BLUE-RED}`.

Just to clarify, an incorrect approach would define CHAIN1 something like this:

```
:CHAIN1 :has_marble :YELLOW, :RED, :BLUE, :RED
```

but querying this would clearly only yield a "bag of marbles" situation.

I would like to be able to:

1. Query the knowledge graph such that I can get back the marbles for each chain in the correct order.
2. Match sequences of marbles between different chains. For example, I might want to get all the chains that have the sequence `:RED-:BLUE-:RED` as a sub-sequence (i.e., `CHAIN1` and `CHAIN3`).

Questions:

1. What would be the best way of building this knowledge graph? Should I store the marbles as RDF sequences using rdf:first/rdf:rest? Or is there a better, more flexible option? If possible, I would like to be able to define the type of relation between the marbles, say `:RED :is_followed_by :BLUE`.
2. Is the type of graph matching I'm after possible? And how about if I'd like to match the sequences using some *properties* that describe each marble? Say, `:BLUE :has_shape :SQUARE`, and match the sequence of marbles by their shape?

Note: What I really want to model are chains of DNA and protein sequences, so if anyone has specific recommendations for such applications, that would be even more helpful.

Comment: there is a paper about the different approaches to model and query lists in RDF: http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-2496/paper2.pdf - there is nothing beyond this paper, For SPARQL 1.2 there is an [open ticket](https://github.com/w3c/sparql-12/issues/46) about a "more friendly list", but whether this will make it into the standard is unclear. Besides that, there was also an OWL List ontology which basically provides a vocabulary for the list entity itself. That's all I'm aware of so far.

Comment: I also have to say, at some point  SPARQL is not the appropriate languge, at least graph traversal and beyond are better suited for proper graph databases and languages like Gremlin, Cypher etc. - and those graph database usually have a more efficient indexing of paths etc. because that's their business.

Comment: if you can provide a small concrete RDF graph sample with the intended query and expected answer people here might help better.

Comment: Thanks for the paper! And regarding SPARQL vs Cypher, I personally don't have experience with the latter, but I'll look into that as well. I'm generally finding it difficult to grasp the main advantages each of the two has, and most comparisons seem to have subjective bias rather than being objective comparisons. Anyway, I might try to reformulated the question with a concrete sample.